# Java Project Building an array in array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys need some help with a java project I am working on.

Basically I have 5 classes TestClass, Building, House, Garage, and HouseRooms

- A building has a number of floors, and a number of windows.
- A house is a building.
- A garage is a building.
- A room has a length, width, a floor covering, and a number of
  closets.
- A house has a number of bathrooms, and an array of Rooms.
- A house has a method that returns the average size of the Rooms.
- A Garage can hold some number of cars, and it may have a cement floor
  or a gravel floor.
- A garage has a length and a width.  (Don’t use the Room class as a
  member of the Garage class.)

The TestClass must have an ArrayList which I have, but I am unsure of how to create an array of rooms for each house with its own objects. I've tried as you can see in the HouseRooms class but don't know if thats the best way to go about.

[image]

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Building> buildings = new ArrayList();
    }
}

public class Building {
    private String buildingType; //House or Garage
    private int floors;
    private int windows;
}

public class House extends Building {
    private int bathrooms;
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList();
}
class Rooms {   
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private String floorCover; 
    private int closets;
}

public class Garage extends Building {
    private int cars;
    private String floorType;
    private double length;
    private double width;
}
```

Comment: A house is a building, so is a garage, but a room is not a house, so `Room` should not extend `House`. Your little image even shows that `Room` extends `Object`, not `House`. --- Also, if a house should have rooms, why did you create a separate class named `HouseRooms`, rather than just adding field `rooms` to `House`?

Comment: Oh I see, but how would I link the Rooms to House? Would I create an Object that Building and Room extend too?

Comment: What do you mean by *"a Building with a House"*? A House *is* a Building. --- Extending objects is not about *linking*. If you think so, then please re-read your Java guide.

Comment: @GinoCasolaro You would "link" them by having a field of type `List<Room>` inside your `House` class.

Comment: Ok its coming back, sorry haven't coded java in about a year.

Comment: @Andreas I would add a field rooms to House but my teacher wants a separate Room class.

Comment: Yes, which is why `rooms` is a `List` of `Room` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum type for buildingType variable

```
 public class Building {
        private BuildingType buildingType; //House or Garage
        private int floors;
        private int windows;

    enum BuildingType{
    HOUSE,GARAGE
    }

    }
```

and Room class shouldn't extend House instead of house should have rooms as:

```
public class House extends Building {
    private int bathrooms;
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, would I still have a separate HouseRooms class, or would I put it all in House.

Comment: you must remove HouseRooms class because when House class seems as
public class House extends Building {
    private int bathrooms;
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList();
}
that mean House has rooms .

Comment: to understand better you can check this oop topics( aggregation composition association)